# SSIS Not Showing Data Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have a very simple ssis package. It's basically pulling in a source and sorting the data. The total number of rows coming in is less than 2000. The database comes from the sample adventure works database that is available from Microsoft during training.

To prove I have everything set up correctly, see images below:

[image: Current ssis build]

[image: Adventure Works Sample data]

[image: Adventure Works preview data[![Play]]

When I go to hit the play button, SSIS says everything ran successfully, but I cannot preview the data, via the data viewer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your package sorts the data but doesn't do anything with it. So it's probably sitting in memory on your computer, sorted, and that's about it. We can't see your data viewer configuration either. What are you really trying to do? Insert data into another table? Sort the data in the existing table? Something seems awry.